# How to close an internet tab with cmd/Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

So I'm writing a Python script to open internet links using cmd. For example:

```
import os
os.system('start http://stackoverflow.com/')
os.system('start http://www.google.com/')
os.system('start http://www.facebook.com/')
```

After I open them I do:

```
import time 
time.sleep(60)
```

So I can wait a minute before doing anything else. What I can't seem to find anywhere is a way to close these tabs after I have opened them for 60 seconds? Is there a command I can use to close internet tabs in cmd?

Note: I'm using **Windows 8**, **Python 2.7.9**, and **Google Chrome**

Answer (score 6):

You can start processes and then kill them after 60 seconds.

```
from subprocess import Popen, check_call

p1 = Popen('start http://stackoverflow.com/')
p2 = Popen('start http://www.google.com/')
p3 = Popen('start http://www.facebook.com/')

time.sleep(60)
for pid in [p1.pid,p2.pid,p3.pid]:
    check_call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID', str(pid)])
```

[replacing-os-system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system)

If you want to open a browser with three tabs then close I would use selenium or something similar:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


dr = webdriver.Chrome()

dr.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
dr.execute_script("$(window.open('http://www.google.com/'))")
dr.execute_script("$(window.open('http://facebook.com/'))")

time.sleep(5)
dr.close()
dr.switch_to.window(dr.window_handles[-1])
dr.close()
dr.switch_to.window(dr.window_handles[-1])
dr.close()
```

[chromedriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver), [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: @logic, looks like killing processes on windows is not straight forward I will edit

Comment: windoze! try `p1 = Popen('exec start http://www.facebook.com/',shell=True)` then `p1.kill()` again

Comment: pretty sure it is the shell=True causing the problem,  do you have psutil installed? If so try http://pastebin.com/xkHakBkn, also can you open the page using the chrome.exe?

Comment: when you use shell=True all that gets killed is the actual shell. I would try installing psutil, you can just `pip install psutil`,  out of interest does the /c command cause an error?

Comment: @logic. did you try  psutil? You could start the process with win32api but that is a lot more involved

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the webpages?

Comment: what are you doing exactly, there must be more to it than just opening and closing a tab. You know there are many ways to open a browser in python without starting a subprocess

Comment: @logic, really using selenium to do this or something similar would be a lot easier

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use the keyboard shortcuts:

```
import keyboard

# here goes your code... 

keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+w') # closes the last tab
```

This will just close the last tab, not all (or as many as you want, starting from the last)

Comment: As this isn't part of the standard library I'm guessing it's [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard).

Comment: Yes Mark Lawrence, I should have clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome got it's own process and resource management. 
the lifecycle of a new `chrome.exe <url>` is short. a new `chrome` process communicate and passes the new tab request to another `chrome` process and exits immediately. therefore the `PID` of the new `chrome.exe` is irrelevant and killing it will not going to close the newly opened tabs (as suggested in the sibling answer).

**However, You can use this Naive alternative:**

1. open `chrome.exe <url>`
2. wait 60 secs
3. close all `chrome.exe` processes

**for example:**

```
from subprocess import Popen
import time

urls = ['http://www.facebook.com/', 'http://www.google.com/']

for url in urls:
    Popen(['start', 'chrome' , url], shell=True)

time.sleep(60)

Popen('taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe', shell=True)
```

---

## Note - it will close ALL of your `chrome` instances

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your first comment :) you are right, it can be simplified to a single string. just edited

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
main_window = browser.current_window_handle
```

## Open new tab

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
browser.get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django')
```

## Wait 10 sec and close the new tab.

```
time.sleep(10)
```

## Close New tab. The first tab remains open.

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```