# How to close web browser using python

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I have opened a webbrowser window using `webbrowser.open(url)` in python now I want to close the webbrowser opened using python. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186844/how-to-close-an-internet-tab-with-cmd-python

Comment: please read this: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/317yct/i_have_code_that_opens_a_webbrowser_now_how_do_i/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no webbrowser.close, you can use these codes to close the task(in Windows OS):

First Import os package with

```
import os
```

then use system function to kill the task

```
os.system("taskkill /im firefox.exe /f")
os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
```

Comment: What's the extension we'd use for a chrome incognito window?

Answer (score 5):

For MacOS, you can use below command:

```
os.system("killall -9 'Google Chrome'")
```