# Force Close webpage in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a program which automatically closes the website open in a browser if it opens any webpage other than some exceptions.
Please help me out!

Comment: please, show to us what you tried so far.

Comment: @EduardoColtri I only did a program for force closing applications....I did not start this one yet coz idk what to do

Comment: Already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568922/how-to-close-web-browser-using-python