# How can I close a web site from a python app?

Tags: python, php, mysql, w3m

I have a Linux python app, that runs a web php app on a server, that requests data from a MySql database and saves the answer in a text file on the server. I can download the text file from the server using pysftp however ... I have to manually close the web app.
Then I start another python app passing the text file data to it.

I can't find find a way to close the web app using code.
I like w3m because it runs from the terminal.  I can close it using Shift+Q. I can close with the cap locks on and pushing Q so it doesn't require two keys. But I can't find a way to send Shift+Q programmatically. I have also tried and can run Firefox, and Chrome from python but can't find a way to close them using code in my php app or python app either.

I have tried the obvious:

```
<?php echo chr(81); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your web app is running on a browser:

> There is no webbrowser.close, you can use these codes to close the
> task(in Windows OS):
>
> First Import os package with
>
> `import os`
>
> then use system function to kill the task
>
> `os.system("taskkill /im firefox.exe /f") os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")`
>
> For MacOS, you can use below command:
>
> `os.system("killall -9 'Google Chrome'")`

source: [How to close web browser using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568922/how-to-close-web-browser-using-python)

Comment: `killall -9` is bad, it will close all instances of chrome being used by other apps too. A better way could be to kill browser-instance (tab) specifc pid.