# How to open URL for 1 min and closed after the 1 min in python?

Tags: python, time, python-webbrowser

I want to open a URL for 1 minute and then close it automatically after the 1 minute has passed using Python, how can I do that it please?

```
import time
import webbrowser
open('https://www.example.com')
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Use selenium then .

Comment: If you use webbrowser then you have to kill the task. for windows : `os.system("taskkill /im firefox.exe /f")`

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29187003/6660373?

Answer (score 3):

Using `Subprocess`:

```
import time
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["firefox", "https://www.example.com"])
time.sleep(60) 
p.kill()
```

Using `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
sleep(60)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The webbrowser module is not great for this. What you could do is kill the process started by `open`, but `urllib` is the better way to handle these things

Answer (score 1):

You can try using keyboard shortcuts:

```
import keyboard
import time
import os

os.system('start https://www.example.com')

time.sleep(60) # note I changed this from 5 to 60 seconds 

keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+w') # closes the last tab opened
```